# Action Trigger when I hold UIButton for 2 second in iPhone

Tags: ios4, ios-simulator, iphone

I have a `UIButton` in my application and an action which is triggered when I TouchDown `UIButton`.

Is it possible to detect a Touch-and-Hold on the `UIButton` on the iPhone? I want my action to trigger when the user holds the button for 2 seconds or more.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`UILongPressGestureRecognizer` is what you need. For example,

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress_gr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doAction:)];
[longPress_gr setMinimumPressDuration:2]; // triggers the action after 2 seconds of press
[yourButton addGestureRecognizer:longPress_gr];
```

To let your action get triggered only once(ie., when the 2 seconds duration is over), make sure you have your `doAction:` method looks something like this,

```
- (void)doAction:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

        // Your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code, its working fine. But there is one problem my action trigger two times. First action trigger after 2 second and second when I end touches.

Comment: @Arman: Oh.. I've edited my answer. I guess that should work. check it out.

Comment: Thanks Simon. Its really helpful for me.

Answer (score 2):

On the other way you can use [this NBTouchAndHoldButton](https://github.com/balazsnemeth/NBTouchAndHoldButton). This is exactly what you want, and it is very easy to implement it:

```
TouchAndHoldButton * pageDownButton = [TouchAndHoldButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[pageDownButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pageDownAction:) forTouchAndHoldControlEventWithTimeInterval:0.2];
```

Good luck!