# Cancel Press If Button Not Held Long Enough Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a UIButton in Objective-C and I want to cancel the press if the button is let go before 10 seconds. How would I go about this?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: then You need UILongPressGestureRecognizer...&& this will be helpful **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815296/action-trigger-when-i-hold-uibutton-for-2-second-in-iphone**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660282/uibutton-with-longpress-and-touchup-inside

Comment: check my answer don't waste your time

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this:

```
[yourButton addGestureRecognizer:[[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                   initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handle:)]];
```

Create an NSTimer property called timer:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *timer;
```

And a counter:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) int counter;

- (void)incrementCounter {
self.counter++;
```

}

```
- (void)handle:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer)gesture {
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
     self.counter = 0;
     self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(incrementCounter) userInfo:nil repeats:yes];
    }
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    [self.timer invalidate];
    }
 }
```

So when the gesture begins start a timer that fires the incrementation method every second until the gesture ends. In this case you'll want to set the minimumPressDuration to 0 otherwise the gesture won't start straight away.
In this way you can get your timer and put a condition on button pressed with self.counter = 10 seconds.

Please let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

To stick with a `UIButton`'s intended design, I would suggest utilizing a `UIButton`'s `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` and `UIControlEventTouchDown` control events.

(*hint: `-addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` method*)

### Logically:

1. Start a timer on `UIControlEventTouchDown`
2. Stop the timer on `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`
3. In the `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` action method

   - check the timer duration (if 10seconds then perform action else don't)

---

### Example:

---

### Prerequisites:

1. Declare following objects (*in the .h file of the class*)

   - `UIButton *btnTest;`
   - `NSTimer *tmrTest;`
   - `int i_tmrCount;`

---

### Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //...

    i_tmrCount = 0;

    btnTest = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btnTest setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 100, 100, 30)];
    [btnTest setTitle:@"Test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //method connected to the button pressed down event alone
    [btnTest addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTestActStart:) 
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    //method connected to the button pressed down and released event
    [btnTest addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTestAct:) 
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btnTest];
}
```

---

```
- (void)btnTestActStart:(UIButton *)sender
{
    tmrTest = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                               target:self
                                             selector:@selector(timerDo)
                                             userInfo:nil
                                              repeats:YES];
}

-(void)timerDo
{
    i_tmrCount++;
}
```

---

```
- (void)btnTestAct:(UIButton *)sender
{
    //stop the timer
    [tmrTest invalidate];

    if (i_tmrCount >= 10) {
        //do something
        NSLog(@"action");
    } else {
        //do nothing
        NSLog(@"reset");
    }

    //reset i_tmrCount to initial state (to handle next occurrence)
    i_tmrCount = 0;
}
```

---

**PS:** If it were a `UILabel` then go with `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` but for a `UIButton`, it won't be ideal because you'll have to drop the implementation of the method connected to the button's `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` and instead make the method connected to the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` as the main button method (*it feels kinda dirty*)

Comment: `1.` and `2.` are the same... typo? Perhaps you meant "touch down"?