# UILongPressGestureRecognizer does not do anything

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I wanted to have a UI button respond only if it is being held for more than a set number of seconds. So I used UILongPressGestureRecognizer as so:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var holdButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func holdButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let recognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPressHappened))
    recognizer.minimumPressDuration = 2.0
    view.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
}
```

and the handler

```
@objc func longPressHappened(gestureReconizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
    holdButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.7254902124, green: 0.4784313738, blue: 0.09803921729, alpha: 1)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
         print ("Sucess")
    }
   
}
```

As you can see, i have used DispatchQueue and tried to change the color of the button but neither are working. Can someone please tell me why?

**Update** :-
I am confused with implementing the methods given in the answer so i thought i will give my full code again

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var holdButton: UIButton! {
didSet {
    
         let recognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self,action: #selector(longPressHappened))
         recognizer.minimumPressDuration = 2.0
         holdButton.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
     }
 }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    holdButton.layer.cornerRadius = 150
    holdButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    holdButton.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
    holdButton.clipsToBounds = true
}


@objc func longPressHappened(gestureReconizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
    holdButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.7254902124, green: 0.4784313738, blue: 0.09803921729, alpha: 1)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
         print ("Sucess")
    }
   
}

}
```

Comment: Tap button once and then try long press, is it working then?

Comment: check out the Answer if it works at your end ?

Comment: @Frankenstein no it does not. Thanks for the attempt!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to create custom button using UIView. Add a long press gesture to that view and upon required time triggered the delegate/Closures.

```
func addLongPressGesture() {
    let recognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleLongPress(_:)))
    recognizer.minimumPressDuration = 3.0 // Duration
    customButton.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
}

@objc
func handleLongPress(_ gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if gestureRecognizer.state == .began {
        // Perform your functionality here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but just two questions, the code only woeks if i modify the #selector to read  `#selector(longPressed_:)` and it gets triggered twice when it should only get triggered once.

Comment: i figured it out, you need to put  `if recognizer?.state == .began {` in `longPressed`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Kingteena are you trying to add this gesture on button or view?

Comment: I am trying to implement in a button. Also can you tell me why the underscore is needed? I am sort of new to swift

Comment: @Kingteena Please checkout named and unnamed parameters in swift, basically with underscore you can ignore the parameter name and just pass value. Updated my answer, so that it will benefit future SO user!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add gesture to button instead of view

```
@IBOutlet weak var holdButton: UIButton! {
      didSet {
            let recognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self,action: #selector(longPressHappened))
            recognizer.minimumPressDuration = 2.0
            holdButton.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! unfortunately this does not work for me... perhaps this is an error of implementing it in my end? i'm new to swift and have not used didSet and UILongPressGestureRecognizer so i might have done it wrong

Answer (score 0):

Add the gesture in your `viewDidLoad` instead:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //...
    let recognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self,action: #selector(longPressHappened))
    recognizer.minimumPressDuration = 2.0
    holdButton.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whole isue is because, you are using `UIBUtton` for gesture recogniztion. you have to use `Uiview` for `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` .

If you want the animations like `UIButton` then you have to use manual animations or you can have ready to made code fro internet.

If you need further help, you can ask in comment

Comment: So if i use ` UILongPressGestureRecognizer `,  the user can tap anywhere on the screen and the code will be triggered even without the user tapping on the button or...?

Answer (score 0):

So I was looking at other answers and I found that all of them were in Objective-C which was why i posted this question... So because the answers were not working for me i used Swiftify to convert the code from [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815296/action-trigger-when-i-hold-uibutton-for-2-second-in-iphone?noredirect=1&lq=1), and after some modification, it worked.

Here is the code snippet

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //...
       let longPress_gr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doAction(_:)))
       longPress_gr.minimumPressDuration = 2 // triggers the action after 2 seconds of press
       holdButton.addGestureRecognizer(longPress_gr)
}
```

and then the objective-c function to make sure the code only gets triggered once after the long press happened

```
@objc func doAction(_ recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer?) {

    if recognizer?.state == .began {
        print("sucess")
    }
}
```

(However, I cant understand the difference between this answer and some of the answers given above... can someone comment on how it work)